# I would like to add a line in a file on a linux shell

Tags: linux

I am new to the Linux Command Line and truth be told, I am a little intimidated be all the commands.  I would like to add a line between find. What commands are there for? There is a lot out there about files but nothing about the content.

```
cd /applbeh/cr/acr/xfb/send/
find Mt940 -type f -iname '*MT940*' | xargs -r rm -v
find Mt940 -type f -iname '*OVK*' | xargs -r rm -v
```

Thanks

Comment: *"between find"*? what do you mean with *find*?

Comment: @Conseil It's quite unclear what it is you want to do. Manually edit a file? Write a script that modifies a file? What is the code in the question? Moreover, what has this got to do with PuTTY?

Comment: I mean that after the line that starts with [find Mt940...]  I would like to insert a line [ find camt053 -type f iname ...]

Comment: @Conseil So... open the file in your favourite editor and type away. With what do you need help?

Comment: i use the PuTTY/ssh to add a line to a file. Yes, and i want manually to add the line.

Comment: Thanks everone for your contribution. Finally I got the the line using the general command [echo "mytext">>file]

Answer (score 0):

A oneliner to add a line to a file is:

```
echo 'line' >> file
```

With `line` (without the quotes), the content of the line you wish to add and `file` the name of the file you wish to write to.

`>>` is an IO redirection that means *append*, it means you add the given output (`echo 'line'`) thus `line` to the file.

Comment: this is what  I did  echo "find Camt053 -type f -iname '*OVK*' | xargs -r rm -v">>testrun_acr.kshoud
-ksh: testrun_acr.kshoud: cannot create [Permission denied]

Comment: Well `testrun_acr.kshoud -ksh` is not a file, since you provide a `flag`. Is it a command?